# C# Settings without writing to App.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have C# application in VisualStudio with a `SecretSettings.settings` (application settings), which I do not want to write into `App.config`.

I do not want a plain user to read these settings from `MyApp.exe.config`, but I want a power user to be able to modify `MyApp.exe.config`, add `SecretSettings` section and change the application behaviour.

Everything is working fine when I manually edit `App.config` after every change in `SecretSettings.settings` and remove the settings from there. But is there any way to tell the VisualStudio to stop merging `SecretSettings.settings` into `App.config`? I am just a man and forget to correct `App.config` occasionally.

Comment: Not an answer, but advice. I usually use Registry for such settings. Average Joe usually does not know what registry is, let alone locate and modify application specific keys. A power user (system admin maybe?) can easily be directed to registry for configuration. Default values can be pushed into registry on the first time the application is launched.

Comment: Maybe you should use [Encrypting Configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a Visual Studio extension called `Slow Cheetah` or `Configuration Transformation`. Both are pretty good at what they do, which is to inject or modify app.config values at compile time.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859